# Acesso PHP remoto com Ajax - Retorno é o próprio código do arquivo PHP

Tags: php, ajax

Tenho um sistema conforme abaixo: HTML no lado do cliente, JavaScript e PHP no lado do servidor. A idéia é ter um espécie de WebService, onde uma página HTML (tem que ser HTML pois vai rodar em um app feito em HTML5 com o Intel XDK) solicita informação para o servidor, onde é o PHP que faz o retorno.

O problema: Quando executo desta forma, o resultado é o código do PHP, conforme abaixo, ou seja, o servidor não processou nada, retorna tudo que está escrito no arquivo PHP.

```
<?php 
 echo $data = date("d/m/Y H:i:s ");
?>
```

Se carrego o `index.html` no mesmo servidor onde estão os outros arquivos, ai o retorno é a data, que seria o esperado, ou seja, só roda se estiver tudo no mesmo servidor, mas o que preciso é um arquivo HTML remoto, rodando em qualquer computador que acessa o serviço PHP/JS no servidor.

O que está errado nesta configuração? Tem um forma mais prática de fazer isto?

No computador local (`C:/`), tenho o arquivo HTML com o código:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.c...n.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.example.c...S.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<a href="javascript:test();">Clique aqui...</a>   
</body>
</html>
```

Do lado do servidor `http://www.example.com` eu tenho um JavaScript e um PHP:

Arquivo JavaScript:

```
function test() {
    var jqxhr = $.ajax( "servidor.php" )

    .done(function(response) {
    alert( "success" );
    alert(response);
    })
    .fail(function(response) {
    alert( "error" );
    alert(response);
    })
    .always(function(response) {
    alert( "complete" );
    alert(response);
    });
}
```

Arquivo PHP:

```
<?php  
     echo $data = date("d/m/Y H:i:s ");
 ?>
```

---

### Atualização

Testei em algumas situações,  e agora localizei onde está o problema que eu não consigo retorno do PHP. Está no endereçamento do JS, que não consegue chegar no arquivo PHP no servidor.

Assim não funciona:

```
$.post('http://www.iodasistemas.meximas.com/JSON/servidor.php', 
    {comando:true}, function(data){
```

Assim funciona:

```
 $.post('servidor.php', {comando:true}, function(data){
```

Resumindo, a questão toda é que o HTML sempre chama o JS, mas ele não consegue chegar no PHP. Seja rodando todos os arquivos no servidor, ou um HTML solto no computador.
O erro que mencionei ocorria pois eu tinha um arquivo servidor.php na mesma pasta do HTML local, assim era esse arquivo que ele lia, e não o do servidor.
Parece que ao carregar o JS, ele passa a trabalhar local, e não roda remoto.

Como fazer o JavaScript Chegar no PHP usando um endereço completo `http://....`?

Comment: Sei que pode parecer absurdo mas, o servidor onde os arquivos PHP estão tem PHP instalado?

Answer (score 1):

Tentei fazer assim no javascript:

```
function test(){

$.post('http://www.seusite.com.br/servidor.php', {comando:true}, function(data){

alert(data);

});
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Agradeço a ajuda de todos. Consegui fazer funcionar. Abaixo os códigos.

Só gostaria que alguém me desse uma luz de como passar um valor para o arquivo PHP que está no servidor, e como tratar este valor no PHP.

Assim consigo fazer uma requisição para o servidor e ter um retorno processado.

Arquivo HTML  + JS (pode salvar em qualquer lugar ou qualquer computador que roda)

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
var urlTeste = 'http://www.meuservidor.com/servidor.php?jsoncallback=?';
$(document).ready(function() {
//Mensagem enquanto não carrega a pagina
$('#resultado').html('Carregando...');

$.getJSON(urlTeste,null, function(data){
$('#resultado').html(data);   
});
}); 
</script>
```

Arquivo PHP (no servidor www.meuservidor.com/servidor.php)

```
<?php
$var = date("d/m/Y H:i:s "); 
echo $_GET["jsoncallback"] . '(' . json_encode($var) . ');';    
?>
```

Comment: Olá, bem-vindo ao Stack Overflow em Português! Que bom que conseguiu resolver o problema usando JSONP (que é o nome dessa técnica com callback que você usou). Mas essa pergunta acabou saindo muito do formato do site, que é bem diferente de um fórum. O ideal teria sido postar a solução para a sua primeira pergunta, e abrir uma nova pergunta separada para a questão que surgiu a partir daí. Você acabou postando novas perguntas na área de respostas, criando uma espécie de diálogo. Por favor dê uma olhada na nossa [help] para orientações mais detalhadas. Espero poder ajudar em futuras dúvidas! :)

Answer (score 0):

Você pode tentar usar jSON para ver se consegue retornar o que você quer.

```
$.getJSON("www.suapagina.com.br",
              function (data) {

                      alert(data.mensagem);
              }
            )
            .success(function() { alert("Sucesso"); })
            .error(function() { alert("Erro"); })
            .complete(function() {  alert("Completo"); });
```

Comment: Já tentei desta forma, mas assim só roda se todos os arquivos estiverem no servidor. Só consegui roda com o HTML remoto mesmo com o códgio acima.